# How to setup Vue.js correctly?

Tags: vue.js

I have a website and I am using Vue.js, I used **Vue.createApp** for different places, such header, product page and so on and all mount by an ID, when I tried to make new one that can used on all pages it didn't work or I didn't know to setup it correctly.

```
<script type="application/javascript">
  Vue.createApp({
    data() {
      return {...}
    },
  }).mount('#header')
</script>
```

```
<script type="application/javascript">
  Vue.createApp({
    data() {
      return {...}
    },
  }).mount('#app')
</script>
```

all others ID are nested in app

```html
<div id="app">
  <div id="header">
  ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: These multiple nested apps don't make sense, Vue isn't a glorified jQuery. You can have only `<div id="app">`, and the rest of the markup comes from app component, this is how it's usually done

Comment: Normally you only mount one Vue instance, and use for example vue-router to handle navigation through multiple "pages", or just nested components for a single page layout